# Custom Loader isn't working. Probably an easy fix

Tags: android, loader

I'm trying to make a custom loader but it no worky. It's probably an easy fix and I'm just brain farting here.

Class to load:

```
public class Exercise{
...
}
```

Loader:

```
public class ExerciseLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Exercise> {
...
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment implements android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Exercise>{
...
@Override
public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Exercise> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    ExerciseLoader exerciseLoader = new ExerciseLoader(
        getActivity(),
        exerciseRowId
    );

    return exerciseLoader;
}
```

The problem is where it says "return exerciseLoader" there is a redlined error saying

> Incompatible Types
>
> required android.support.v4.content.Loader.......com.MYPATH.Exercise
>
> found com.MYPATH.ExerciseLoader

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You should check the package you have imported for 'AsyncTaskLoader'. Make sure you have imported this package in 'ExcerciseLoader'. 'import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check which version of `AsyncTaskLoader<Exercise>` your extend: the one from `android.content` package or the one from `android.support.v4.content`. From your further app's logic you need to use the one from the support library.